# Is there a "standard" extension to the .mtl format which allows specular, normal or parallel maps?

Tags: opengl, 3d, wavefront, bump-mapping

Reading about the [MTL material format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file#Material_template_library) commonly used with the Wavefront OBJ format, I discovered that it doesn't support additional features like specular mapping, parallel mapping, bump mapping, etc.

I'm wondering, is there a commonly used extension or modification of this format which supports specifying these features? If not, is there a more modern equivalent of MTL which is commonly used with OBJ?

EDIT: it appears the wiki article is outdated, on the one hand, it says

> The MTL format, although still widely used, is outdated and does not fully support later technologies such as specular maps and parallax maps.

But later shows how to do specular and bump maps.

Comment: Reading the same document I see map_Ks (specular mapping) and map_bump (bump mapping). So the second one you list is the only one missing. And no there is no formal way to specify extensions to the format.

Comment: Hmm, interesting! Seems like the article is cocntradictory. For the format, it says "However due to the open and intuitive nature of the format, these can easily be added with a custom MTL file generator." What I want to know is, is there an unofficial but commonly used extension to the format?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no formal extension.

Comment: I realize that, I'm not looking for a formal extension. I'm looking for an informal extension that is popular. Which may not exist, but if so, that's the answer to the question.

Comment: There is no informal extension either.